# Get a reference to the view for a PopUp Menu

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu) that is created dynamically. I need to pass the underlying view for this menu to another method, but I cannot find any way to get a reference to the view itself, just the menu interface and its items.

Ideally, I would do something like this:

```
val popMenu = PopupMenu(mainActivity, view)
popMenu.inflate(menu.route_mode)
popMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this@Class)
menu.show()

viewFunction(popMenu.view)
```

This is not happening in the activity. This is not an Options or Context menu and is not shown in the action bar.

Comment: You probably need to create your own custom view instead of using PopupMenu if you want to manipulate it as a view.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there seems no such method, i.e., you can't find the anchor view from the PopupMenu itself.

I usually create a member in the Activity to remember which View was clicked. Assume it is a Button btnPopupMenu clicked to show the popup menu, something like this:

```
public class MyActivity : Activity {
  ...
  private var _clickedView:View? = null
  ...
  override onCreate() {
    ...
    btnPopupMenu.setOnClickedListener { v ->
      _clickedView = v
      val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, v)
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
  override onOptionItemSelected(menuItem:MenuItem) {
    // use _clickedView here
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not trying to get the anchor view, but the size and position of the menu itself, so saving a field would not work either. 

I went as far as overriding popup menu and trying to get the underlying ListView that way, but gave it up as a bad job.